# RubyMine warning when run bundle install MacOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rubymine

When I've created a new project via RubyMine, 'Create New Project' -> 'Rails' 'New application'. And select the rails and ruby version, after I click create button, it's starts to generate new project. After bundle ends install, in 2 or 3 seconds appears two warning tabs signs:

First tab named `Get available generators list` and consist of:

```
Warning:Get available generators script executes with errors:
Warning:Running via Spring preloader in process 61870
```

Second tab named `Get available rake tasks` and consist of:

```
Warning:[rake --tasks] Running via Spring preloader in process 61869
Warning:[rake --prereqs] Running via Spring preloader in process 61872
```

Need to note, if i create rails project via terminal

```
rails new [name]
bundle install
```

No problems appears.

I really want to get rid of this warnings. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote to RubyMine support.

All this warnings appears because of some bug in RM. They already know about it and going to fix it in the next version.